# Django - Calling ManytoMany Field inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, django, django-modeladmin

I am using Django Model field values inside a Javascript file by using the following code:

```
var action_type =$('#id_strength').val();
```

Here strength is a Charfield.

But the same doesn't work for a ManytoMany Field

```
var action_type =$('#id_batches').val();
```

Batches:

When I viewed the source code, the HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="related-widget-wrapper">
<select name="batches" data-field-name="batches" multiple="multiple" id="id_batches" data-is-stacked="0" class="selectfilter">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't know or care about your Django fields. It only knows about html. What does the html look like?

Comment: HTML looks like this for the batches field:                                       <label for="id_batches">Batches:</label>
<select name="batches" data-field-name="batches" multiple="multiple" id="id_batches" data-is-stacked="0" class="selectfilter">
  <option value="option1">option2</option>
</select>

Comment: I have updated the question with HTML code

Answer (score 0):

So I did some digging and was finally able to get the JQuery to access the field. Since it is a ManytoMany select field, I just had to treat the batches as a select field.

```
var action_type = []
$("#id_batches").each(function(name,val) {
    action_type.push(val.value);
    });
```

Thanks Daniel Roseman for pointing me to right direction